# Installing Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu on btrfs: how to restore boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, btrfs

I've looked at the answers on this question, but none of them solved my problem:

[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

My system is partitioned as follows. `/dev/sdb5` is Ubuntu's root partition.

[image]

I installed Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu. All my Ubuntu partitions (except `swap`) have the `btrfs` filesystem.

Installing Windows left me unable to boot in Ubuntu. Running a live USB, the live Ubuntu was not able to find the Ubuntu partitions using `os-prober`, probably due to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/os-prober/+bug/1294638).

I'd like to get Ubuntu booting again. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use this image and start from USB, when using yumi (pendrivelinux.com) choose install unlisted ISO (grub) option.

http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/

You can detect OSes and also repair grub.

HowTo:

- Insert bootmedia in to its drive (e.g. USB or CD/DVD)
- Set the media to be the first booting device in BIOS
- Then boot; if you used yumi select "grub bootable isos  or xp/7..."
  choose the SGD2
- Find out where your Linux is installed (detect any OS) and select
- Install GRUB using

  sudo grub-install /dev/YOURLINUXDRIVE
- Finished
  -